# Regex: I need to get numbers inside square brackets my regular exp is working in online tester but not in console

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, console

If I try and test the same string it works fine in all the online regex testers but its not working in console. throwing me NOT FOUND Error.
Can anyone guide me.

```
string str='this is a test [12312] email subject [dfasdfa]';
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile('\\[([0-9]*?)\\]');
Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
system.debug('mat'+match.group(1));
```

Regex Tester : http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use find method of the Matcher class.

In my observation, if you use `m.find()` function it search for the string based on your pattern then returns true and you will get the value in debug

```
string str='this is a test [12312] email subject [dfasdfa]';
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile('\\[([0-9]*?)\\]');
Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
if (match.find()) 
{
   system.debug(match.group(1)); 
}
```

If you run this code you will get matched string i.e `[12312]`..

If you don't use `m.find()` function then pattern will never search for string that you are looking for and you will get nothing

```
string str='this is a test [12312] email subject [dfasdfa]';
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile('\\[([0-9]*?)\\]');
Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
system.debug(match.group(1));
```

If you run this code you will get no match found..

**matches() method**

> The Matcher class Javadoc states, "The matches() method attempts to
>   match the entire input sequence against the pattern." Therefore, your
>   pattern must match the entire input sequence.

**The find() method**

> As mentioned earlier, another approach is to use the find method of
>   the Matcher class. The find method does not require your pattern to
>   match the entire String.

**[Documentation](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-pattern-matching-matches-method-not-working)**

Answer (score 0):

My regex works fine. I havent checked the condition whether the regex string is true or false, once its true i am able to get the Substring.

```
if (m.find()) 
{
   system.debug(m.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: If someone else has already answered your question, you should accept their answer as correct rather than posting the same answer yourself.